# Render HTMLDivElement in React

Tags: html, dom, reactjs, render

I have this problem where I'm trying to render a HTMLDivElement using React, however I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `VirtualList`
```

In my React Component class I have this code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class VirtualList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.container = document.createElement('div');
    }

    renderList() {
        let container = this.container;

        // Manipulate container etc.

        return container;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify why do you want to use `document.createElement`?

Comment: It isn't react way to deal with dom.

Comment: @AlexanderT. I wrote some plain javascript code with a bunch of logic behind it, so I wanted to in a sense, port that code into React, thinking you could just render the HTMLDivElement object

Answer (score 2):

[**DOCS:**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements)

**`ReactElements` are not to be confused with DOM Elements.**

You can create React Element through React.createElement.

```
this.container = React.createElement('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but I just stumbled across the same problem.

You can modify your code to create a ref to the div, which can then be treated as a normal HTML-element. First, create the div:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.container = document.createElement('div');
        this.reference = React.createRef();
    }
```

Then, you add the ref to the correct div:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div ref={this.reference}>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

You can append whenever you like, but I'd do it after the component mount:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    this.reference.current.appendChild(this.container());
}
```

See [here](https://filipmolcik.com/react-children-vanilla-html-element/) for an implementation with functional components